# C# what does (bool ? string : string) do?

Tags: c#

Looking for help working out what the code in return does / is called

```
private string MakeOrderKey(string s1, string s2)
{
   bool b = (string.Compare(s1, s2) < 0);
   return ((b ? s1 : s2) +  "/" + (b ? s2 : s1));
}
```

Comment: It's called a [Ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: You should google `C# "?" operator`. That will lead you to the documentation, or at the very least the name to look up.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You have that backwards. It will return `s1` if `b` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's equivalent to

```
if (b)
{
     return s1;
}
else
{
     return s2;
}
```

Edit: As Alexey pointed out, I should clarify.  `return` here isn't the `return` from your specific function it's just saying that the statement `(b ? s1 : s2)` will evaluate to either `s1` or `s2` based on the value of `b`.

Learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: Note: `return` is not the calling function's `return`

Answer (score 0):

It's comparing the strings represented by s1 and s2 and returns a string like
"bar/foo" in the comparative order of the strings.

Note that string.Compare may have issues with casing and special characters, consider using string.CompareOrdinal instead.